# Segmentation Fault Error when I try to run program

Tags: c++

I keep getting a segmentation fault error. I am trying to make the user type in integers and return the indices of the sums in the vector. Please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void print (const vector<int> *result) {
    cout << "[";
    for (int i {0};i<(*result).size();++i) {
        cout << (*result).at(i) + " ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}

vector<int> *method(const vector<int> *vec,int value) {
    vector<int> *newvec {nullptr};
    bool done {false};
    int i = (*vec).size()-1;
    while (!done && i >= 0) {
        if (value >= (*vec).at(i)) {
            value -= (*vec).at(i);
            (*newvec).push_back(i);
        } 
        if (value == 0) {
            cout << "done" << endl;
            done = true;
        } else {
            --i;
        }
    }
    return newvec;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    int Numbers;
    cout << "Enter a list of numbers (put spaces inbetween): ";
    while (cin >> Numbers && Numbers != -1) {
        v.push_back(Numbers);
    }
    cout << endl;
    int number {};
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << endl;

    vector<int> *results = method(&v,number);
    print(results);
//del results;

    return 0;
}
```

I am not too sure why, but the segmentation error keeps appearing. Is it something I am not understanding with the logic? I believe that it involves the pointers, but am not too sure.

Comment: segmentation **fault** ?

Comment: Refrain from all this usage of pointers and just use objects.  There is no need for pointers in your program.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried a debugger? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Pointers are objects too *\*ducks\** ;)

Answer (score 2):

vector *newvec never gets created as a vector, so is just a pointer to a vector, and then you use it for inserting values.

It would be better to not use pointers in that case and return/use references to the objects instead.

ie:

```
vector<int> method(const vector<int> &vec,int value) {
  vector<int> newvec;
  bool done {false};
  int i = vec.size()-1;
  while (!done && i >= 0) {
    if (value >= vec.at(i)) {
        value -= vec.at(i);
        newvec.push_back(i);
    } 
    if (value == 0) {
        cout << "done" << endl;
        done = true;
    } else {
        --i;
    }
  }
  return newvec;
}
```

and do similar for the other function calls and within main.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> *newvec {nullptr};
```

Here you literally create a null pointer.

You then try to dereference it and use the vector it points to, which doesn't exist.

You have to actually create a vector.

In general I would advise getting rid of all these pointers; you don't need them, and you have already found out how much more complex and error-prone they make your code.

Just create nice, normal vectors in the usual manner.